# How do I interpolate JS variables into css classes?

Tags: javascript, angular

So in ng1, I could do the following:

```
angular.module('foo').component('foo', {
template:
    `<style type="text/css">
        .branding-color {
            color: {{ $ctrl.brandingColor }} !important;
        }

        .branding-color-after:after {
            background-color: {{ $ctrl.brandingColor }} !important;
        }

        .branding-color-before:before {
            background-color: {{ $ctrl.brandingColor }} !important;
        }

        .branding-color-border-before:before {
            border-color: {{ $ctrl.brandingColor }} !important;
        }

        .branding-color-bg {
            background-color: {{ $ctrl.brandingColor }};
        }

        button.button-primary, span.button-primary, a.button-primary, div.button-primary, .button-primary {
            background-color: {{ $ctrl.brandingColor }};
        }

        .button-primary.ty-sticky:enabled {
            border: 1px solid {{ $ctrl.brandingColor }} !important;
        }
    </style>`,
controller(API) {
    const defaultBrandingColor = 'white';

    API.Foobar.getStuff().then((response) => {
        this.brandingColor = _.get(response.data, 'brandingColor', defaultBrandingColor); // return a hex code
    });
},
});
```

I am trying to emulate the same behaviour but can't get it work. I've tried using a  tag inside my component template and using the component's styles metadata, but in both of these cases ng2 will not interpolate my brandingColor.

Any idea how I could solve this? Alternatively I'll gladly accept any other solution that allows me to provide global css classes with interpolated colors.

Answer (score 0):

That's not supported in Angular2.

Use

```
[ngClass]="{'class1': boolValue1, 'class2': boolValue2 }"
```

or any of the other variants [`ngClass`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html) provides.

Comment: What you're suggest is something entirely different. I want to create those classes not consume them

Comment: You can also use `ngStyle` but you can't use binding in CSS because that's not supported. They hopefully eventually support CSS variables.

Comment: Hm I was afraid this would be the answer. Guess I'll have to go the route of good ol' `document.createElement`

Answer (score 0):

If you use `` you can passe variables like this

```
let var = "#000000";
var css = `body { background: ${var} }`
```

CSS can be passed to `Component` in this way

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styles: [
        `
            .grid { height: 90vh }
            .column { max-width: 450px }
            .form { text-align: left }
        `
    ]
})
```

Comment: And what would the next step be? This doesn't answer the question in regards to angular2

Comment: While I appreciate your effort, I think you should read the question again